# MFC CDocument: How to read contents of database files created by defunct app?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I have almost zero experience coding in Visual Studio, MFC, etc. But I've got several data files that were created in a now-defunct MFC application, which I need to migrate to another format.

Unfortunately there's really no good way, within the application itself, to extract the data (short of copy-pasting hundreds or even thousands of records individually). And viewing the files themselves, i.e. in a Hex Editor, has proven fruitless; even though the raw data stored by the app is text-based, the database files are encoded in some cryptic binary format.

So far I've been able to determine that the app was written using MFC and that it uses the CDocument class (or a simple derivative thereof) to store the files. I understand that CDocument-based data files have something to do with serializing the data, but I'm not sure how to make sense of the encoding.

1. Does anyone know enough about MFC to explain to me how CDocument actually works?
2. Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to decode these files to extract the text?

Comment: CDocument does not provide any archiving by itself. It just exposes the methods the derived classes usually implement. As for the encryption: just look for references for some known encryption mechanisms in your "old" MFC code, like blowfish or such. If you find any, you could scan the code to see if you find something obvious variables, like "password" or "key". Then, knowing the key and the encryption method you will be able to decrypt it very easily

Comment: I suspected (or rather feared) that might be the case. Without access to the program's source, I don't know that it's going to be possible to decode the data; I may end up having to just use the copy-paste method. Could take weeks. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once faced an almost identical scenario. I eventually worked out the code to deserialize the data, but it wasn't easy.

Write a small MFC application to do the work, that way you can leverage the same serialization code that the original app used. The topic of reverse engineering a data format is way too complex to answer here. It's probably not encrypted; more likely compressed.

If you're an experienced programmer you should be able to read the MFC source code, then apply that knowledge to the raw data. Not everything can be heuristically determined just by observing the raw data, but if you have an independent way of determining the actual content, it's certainly possible with sufficient work.

Comment: While I'm sure "cha" is probably right -- that even with access to the MFC code I won't know what algorithms are actually applied to the data -- where would be the best place to obtain the MFC source code?

Comment: if you have a visual studio (any "paid" flavour) installed, the mfc source code is in <Visual Studio Folder>\VC\atlmfc\src